# How to add SOAP header with spring-ws

Tags: spring-ws

I created a web service endpoint with Spring-WS:

```
@Endpoint
public class MyEndpoint{

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE, localPart = "MyRequest"
@ResponsePayload
public final MyResponse MyService(@RequestPayload final MyRequest request, SoapHeader header) {

... implementation that creates the reponse ...

return response;
}
```

this creates me the service and generates the WSDL for the service.
But, the  section in my WSDL remains empty.

So, what do I have to do in order to 'populate' the header?

Answer (score 1):

`SoapHeader` doesn't represent an individual header block, but the `soap:Header` element which contains all header blocks as children. This means that your service definition doesn't provide enough metadata to generate a WSDL with a message part bound to a header block. You would have to declare a `SoapHeaderElement` argument with a `@SoapHeader` annotation that specifies the name of the header block. In theory, that would provide enough metadata to generate the expected WSDL, but I believe that in practice Spring-WS doesn't support this. Note that that doesn't mean that the generated WSDL is incorrect. The reason is that it is not mandatory to declare header blocks in the WSDL.